# How can I calculate complex values in LTSpice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I am trying to implement a circuit which contains some complex number of form:

$$
x + jy
$$

So my question is how to represent complex value while writing netlist in LTSPICE.

Comment: Impedance is a complex number typified by an inductor or capacitor in series with R.

Answer (score 1):

The complex part will either be a capacitor or an inductor. Just figure out the value for such component starting out with how much reactance you want. And that component will have to be in series with a resistor which is the real part.

Now if you happen to have a negative real part, you need to simulate a negative resistance, which can be done in LTSpice. [Click here to see how you could do it if you had a negative real part](http://adamsiembida.com/negative-resistor-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need calculations as result of formulas, then using active elements will not be a solution. If so, then you're partly out of luck because LTspice doesn't support complex numbers, except in `.AC` analysis in the waveform arithmetic. Partly, because the only way of doing it is to manually decompose your results into real and imaginary parts (e.g. Euler's formula: `exp(i*x) = cos(x) + i*sin(x)`). It gets complicated, yes, but you can even do FFT in time domain, provided your input is real-valued, only (I did it, but only as a test, because of the immense impact it has for higher N, as you can imagine). The trick is to avoid any calculations that can result in a direct `a+i*b` result, because the `b` will be lost. Only careful separation of terms will give you correct results. I even managed to calculate elliptic filter's roots this way, and not by following the simplified way, but by using real `sn()`&co (which were approximated with theta functions). Which means there's hope, but only so much.